# How to calculate when 75% of task was complete in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Taking E-Commerce scenario, there are some number of products in some categories. How to find out the time when 75% of the product were sold out in each category.

For example, there are 20 Google Pixel (product) in Mobile category, 100 Thinkpads in laptop category and 1000 tees in clothes category at the beginning of the day. 15th Pixel was sold at 6:35:00am, while 20th (last for the day) was sold at 7:00:00am. 75th Thinkpad was sold at 2:40:00pm while 91st (last for the day) was sold at 6:30:00pm. 300th tee was sold by the send of the day (no 75% sale).

Transaction table is:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| ORDER_ID | PRODUCT_ID | SELL_TIME |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| 1        | 1          | 00:00:00  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| 2        | 1          | 00:00:01  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| 15       | 1          | 6:35:00   |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| 20       | 1          | 7:00:00   |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| 1        | 2          | 00:30:00  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| 2        | 2          | 00:35:00  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| 75       | 2          | 14:40:00  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| 91       | 2          | 18:30:00  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| 1        | 3          | 00:30:00  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| 300      | 3          | 21:30:00  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
```

The static inventory table is:

```
+------------+-----------+
| PRODUCT_ID | INVENTORY |
+------------+-----------+
| 1          | 20        |
+------------+-----------+
| 2          | 100       |
+------------+-----------+
| 3          | 1000      |
+------------+-----------+
```

The answer would be:

```
+---+---------+
| 1 |  6:35:00|
+---+---------+
| 2 | 14:40:00|
+---+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was tricky ;)

```
CREATE TABLE trans(ORDER_ID int, PRODUCT_ID int , SELL_TIME date);
INSERT  trans VALUES  (1, 1, '2016-11-30'),
                    (2, 1,   '2016-11-29'),
                    (3, 1,   '2016-11-28'),
                    (4, 1,   '2016-11-27'),
                    (5, 1,   '2016-11-26'),
                    (6, 1,   '2016-11-25'),
                    (7, 2,   '2016-11-24'),
                    (8, 2,   '2016-11-23'),
                    (9, 2,   '2016-11-22'),
                    (10, 2,   '2016-11-21');


CREATE TABLE inventory(PRODUCT_ID int , INVENTORY int);
INSERT  inventory VALUES (1 ,6),
                         (2, 4);


SELECT   x.product_id, 
         Min( 
         CASE 
                  WHEN rank/inventory >= 0.75 THEN sell_time 
                  ELSE NULL 
         end) AS sell_time_75pct 
FROM     ( 
                SELECT ( 
                       CASE product_id 
                              WHEN @currproductid THEN @currow := @currow + 1 
                              ELSE @currow := 1 
                              AND    @currproductid := product_id 
                       end ) AS rank, 
                       product_id, 
                       sell_time, 
                       inventory 
                FROM   ( 
                                  SELECT     trans.product_id, 
                                             sell_time, 
                                             inventory 
                                  FROM       trans 
                                  INNER JOIN inventory 
                                  ON         ( 
                                                        inventory.product_id=trans.product_id)
                                  INNER JOIN 
                                             ( 
                                                    SELECT @currow := 0, 
                                                           @currproductid := '') r 
                                  order BY   product_id , 
                                             sell_time ASC ) x ) x 
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Input:

```
    ORDER_ID    PRODUCT_ID  SELL_TIME
1   6           1           25.11.2016 00:00:00
2   5           1           26.11.2016 00:00:00
3   4           1           27.11.2016 00:00:00
4   3           1           28.11.2016 00:00:00
5   2           1           29.11.2016 00:00:00
6   1           1           30.11.2016 00:00:00
7   10          2           21.11.2016 00:00:00
8   9           2           22.11.2016 00:00:00
9   8           2           23.11.2016 00:00:00
10  7           2           24.11.2016 00:00:00
```

Output:

```
    product_id  sell_time_75pct
1   1           29.11.2016 00:00:00
2   2           23.11.2016 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I tested:

```
SELECT product_id, sell_time
FROM transaction 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, MIN(order_id) AS order_id
  FROM (
    SELECT t.order_id, t.product_id,
      t.order_id >= FLOOR(i.inventory * 0.75) AS is_gt_75
    FROM transaction AS t
    INNER JOIN inventory AS i USING (product_id)
  ) AS _derived1
  WHERE is_gt_75
  GROUP BY product_id
) AS _derived2 USING (product_id, order_id);
```

Output:

```
+------------+-----------+
| product_id | sell_time |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 | 06:35:00  |
|          2 | 14:40:00  |
+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: The Order IDs are not going to be sequential. They are auto-increment field of the table and will increase constantly for all products irrespective of the category or day. I wrote it this way for the sake of simplicity.
My apologies @Bill for not making it clear in the example.